# Is there any application that extensively uses `mprotect`?

Tags: linux, memory-management, system-calls, mprotect

I'm looking for an application for analysis purpose that puts pressure on `mprotect`. I found that JIT compilers use this syscall more than others. But almost all of them (e.g., JVM, Nodejs V8) cache the compiled code at first run resulting in ignoring the `mprotect` calls for the rest of the execution.

My question is, is there any application (like any web server, database, HPC apps, etc) that extensively calls `mprotect`?

Answer (score 0):

I found that Metis benchmark has some MapReduce implementations which extensively call `mprotect`. `wc`, `wr`, and `wrmem` almost dedicates over 95% of their system calls runtime to `mprotect`. The source could be found [here](https://github.com/KunZheng/mosbench/tree/master/metis)

However, a production-grade application is still missing.